# re.sub issue when using group with \number

Tags: python, regex

i'm trying to use a regexp to arrange some text, with `re.sub`.

Let's say it's an almost csv file that I have to clean to make it totally csv.

I replaced all \t by \n doing :

```
t = t.replace("\n", "\t")
```

... and it works just fine. After that, I need to get some \t back to \n, for each of my CSV lines. I use for that this expression :

```
t = re.sub("\t(\d*?);", "\n\1;", t, re.U)
```

The problem is it works... but partially. The \n are added properly, but instead of being followed by my matching group, they are followed by a ^A (according to Vim)

I tried my regexp using a `re.findall` and it works juste fine... so what could be wrong according to you ?

My CSV lines are finally supposed to be like :

```
number;text;text;...;...;\n
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `\1` is interpreted as the ascii character 1.
Try using `\\1` or `r"\n\1;"` .

Comment: You sir, are a bloody mad genius. This was making me want to punch things. Of all the bugs I have encountered, perhaps none are so pernicious as those related to the damned fact that the character set that I see and the character set the computer sees are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Scharron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395939/scharron) said, always always always use raw-string (r'') notation with regexes. Get into that habit and then you won't have to debug weird issues like this.

```
r'\n\1;'
```